# Allowable flexibility in word order in *ordinary verse* vs in *ordinary prose*

Tags: syntax, word-order, poetry

Forgive my amateurish way of asking this, I have no background in linguistics, but I have noticed a phenomenon enough times to want to raise the question.

Have there been studies of how flexible can word order be in *ordinary verse*? In every language I know at least a bit about, it is greater than in ordinary prose but not unlimited.

By ordinary verse I mean that which is not deliberately made to be funny/bizarre (e.g. Yoda of Star Wars) or intellectually very difficult (e.g. James Joyce).

If so, are there studies looking for relationships/patterns across languages?

---

Let me give two examples of what made me think about this.

A famous 1994 Bollywood film song *Didi tera devar deevana* (दीदी तेरा देवर दीवाना) has the following line: "*Dhandha hai yah uska purana*" (धंधा है यह उसका पुराना). If someone wanted to say this in an everyday situation, the word order would probably be "*yah uska purana dhandha hai*" (यह उसका पुराना धंधा है), which means "this is his old business" in the sense in which "these are his typical habits/ways". Clearly what is done in the film version of the sentence is that starting from the ordinary construction you draw a line between the noun "business" and the qualifier "old" and you just throw whatever comes after the line to the beginning of the sentence. The result of this would be weird in prose Hindi but also sound plain wrong in ordinary modern poetry in English, French, etc.

The other example is Latin poetry, which takes this flexibility to a whole other level:

https://www.textkit.com/greek-latin-forum/viewtopic.php?t=10247

Comment: [Have there been studies of how flexible word order **can be**] I don't think you can compare word order *across* languages like that because it would assume some equivalences that are highly questionable. Each language would have to be looked at independently of other languages.